# Type casting in bitwise operations confuses me in C

Tags: c, char, int, bit-manipulation, unsigned

I'm trying to make a part of a ciphering encryption. I'm trying to cipher the data with the keystream I got.

The data is in form uint8_t and the keystream KS is uint32_t.

variable n is the length of the data (in 32 bit chunks obviously)

I have this code:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  wo_data[4*i+0] ^= (uint8_t)(KS[i] >> 24) & 0xff;
  wo_data[4*i+1] ^= (uint8_t)(KS[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
  wo_data[4*i+2] ^= (uint8_t)(KS[i] >>  8) & 0xff;
  wo_data[4*i+3] ^= (uint8_t)(KS[i]      ) & 0xff;
}
```

But it doesn't work even close to expected.

Now if I type cast the data to 32-bit length:

```
uint32_t* data2 = (uint32_t *)wo_data;
for(i=0; i < n; i++)
{
  data2[i] ^= KS[i];
}
```

It starts to work. Can someone explain me why? I would prefer to use the 8-bit length as it is easier to align the ending if the input data is not byte-aligned.

Data is initialized with following:

```
7EC61272 743BF161 4726446A 6C38CED1
66F6CA76 EB543004 4286346C EF130F92
```

KS is initialized with following:

```
F22DB45B 37E71C5B 4EB6F404 CD886C15
9DCA27B1 F062AF46 F8E2F587 8976E8B8
```

I'm expecting following (obviously):

```
8CEBA629 43DCED3A 0990B06E A1B0A2C4
FB3CEDC7 1B369F42 BA64C1EB 6665E72A
```

Comment: *"But it doesn't work even close to expected."* What is expected? What happens instead?

Comment: I have a reference data to encrypt, and with the reference data the first 32-bit chunk is 0x803f7225 where it should be 0x8ceba629. With the wo_data type casted to uint32_t it outputs the right data.

Comment: It would seem you are XORing with initialized data.

Comment: By editing the post, you should make clear what data `KS` and `wo_data` contain initially, what results you get and what results you expect.

Comment: Yes I am. Both wo_data and KS are initialized already.

Comment: "The data is in form uint8_t" ... "Data is initialized with following: 7EC61272 ..."  How does this make any sense? You can't store 32 bit numbers in a `uint8_t`.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: The array is initialized elsewhere and is passed to the function type casted as a `uint8_t` . Is that where I'm going wrong with this one? edit: The array is initialized elsewhere as `uint32_t` , this function takes it with parameter type `uint8_t`. So I type cast the original `uint32_t` when calling this function. But I just don't know how it would change anything. It should not, right?

Comment: Are you sure about the endianness? Also, `& 0xff` _after_ casting to `uint8_t` look superfluous.

Comment: Haha, yes I am, and the bitmask is there because I had no idea what was happening as the code didn't work as expected.

Comment: "The array is initialized elsewhere and is passed to the function type casted as a uint8_t"  That doesn't make any sense either. You have 8 items that go in wo_data and 8 that go in KS. If but wo_data is the 4 byte representations of these 8 integers, then you would have to loop over that data 4*8=32 times. But you only iterate 8 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Arkku stated in the comments, it is an endianness issue.

For instance, if you are in a little-endian machine, K[0]=0xF22DB45B is stored in the following way:

```
@K+0: 5B
@K+1: B4
@K+2: 2D
@K+3: F2
```

Hence, the least significant byte (LSB) of each KS word has to be XORed with `wo_data[4*i+0]`, and so on.

This code gives the expected values:

```
for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
{
    wo_data[4*i+0] ^= ((KS[i]      ) & 0xff);
    wo_data[4*i+1] ^= ((KS[i] >>  8) & 0xff);
    wo_data[4*i+2] ^= ((KS[i] >> 16) & 0xff);
    wo_data[4*i+3] ^= ((KS[i] >> 24) & 0xff);
}
```

The 32-bit version is probably faster since it processes more bytes per instruction. Moreover, it can be vectorized and executed in a more efficient way. See the [generated assembly for the 8- and 32-bit versions](https://godbolt.org/g/VQB1eA). The 8-bit version can be used to process the remaining bytes, if any.

Comment: The efficiency really has nothing to do with vectorization. You can see the compiler generating more efficient code for the 32-bit version if you turn *off* all vector operations. It's just a simple consequence of the fact that processing 4 bytes at a time is faster than processing 1 byte at a time. (I guess maybe that's "vectorization" in the most trivial of senses, but it's not what the term commonly means when applied in an optimization context.)

Comment: As you say, a scalar 32-bit version is more efficient than the 8-bit version (4 bytes vs. 1 byte processed per instruction). But a vectorized 32-bit version is probably faster than a scalar 32-bit version (for AVX, 32 bytes vs. 8 bytes processed per instruction). [See assembly code for both scalar and vectorized versions](https://godbolt.org/g/B9rjRH).